# Find all special characters in a column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I need to find the occurrence of all special characters in a column in `SQL Server 2008`.  So, I don't care about `A, B, C ... 8, 9, 0`, but I do care about `!, @, &,`, etc.

The easiest way to do so, in my mind, would exclude `A, B, C, ... 8, 9, 0`, but if I wrote a statement to exclude those, I would miss entries that had `!` and `A`.  So, it seems to me that I would have to get a list of every non-alphabet / non-number character, then run a `SELECT` with a `LIKE` and `Wildcard` qualifiers.

Here is what I would run:

```
SELECT Col1
FROM TABLE
WHERE Col1 LIKE ('!', '@', '#', '$', '%'....)
```

However, I don't think you can run multiple qualifiers, can you?  Is there a way I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Negatives are your friend here:

```
SELECT Col1
FROM TABLE
WHERE Col1 like '%[^a-Z0-9]%'
```

Which says that you want any rows where `Col1` consists of any number of characters, then one character *not* in the set a-Z0-9, and then any number of characters.

If you have a case sensitive collation, it's important that you use a range that includes both upper and lower case `A`, `a`, `Z` and `z`, which is what I've given (originally I had it the wrong way around. `a` comes before `A`. `Z` comes after `z`)

---

Or, to put it another way, you could have written your original `WHERE` as:

```
Col1 LIKE '%[!@#$%]%'
```

But, as you observed, you'd need to know *all* of the characters to include in the `[]`.

Comment: This looks like this worked....  2 questions though:  What does the `^` do?  And, with the string `A-z0-9`, why should there not be a comma between the search criteria, like this: `^A-z,0-9`?

Comment: @Andomar - yep, corrected. I was initially following my pattern for doing `IsNumeric`, and forgot that we actually wanted characters outside the range.

Comment: @mikebmassey - `^` (as the first character inside `[]`) says "anything *not* in this range. The `[]` block can just contain individual characters - you just put each possible character in turn. The above is equivalent to `[^aAbBcCdD....yYzZ0123456789'`. If you said `[^a-Z,0-9]` then you're just allowing `,` as another character that will not be highlighted.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation - if I wanted to exclude spaces from that list, is there a way to add that to the string?  Maybe something like `[^a-z0-9, " "]`?

Comment: @mikebmassey - Nope, just include a space character: `[^a-Z0-9 ]`. Your example would allow `,`, space (included twice in your range, not treated as an error) and `"` (ditto).

Answer (score 7):

The following transact SQL script works for all languages (international). The solution is not to check for alphanumeric but to check for not containing special characters.

```
DECLARE @teststring nvarchar(max)
SET @teststring = 'Test''Me'
SELECT 'IS ALPHANUMERIC: ' + @teststring
WHERE @teststring NOT LIKE '%[-!#%&+,./:;<=>@`{|}~"()*\\\_\^\?\[\]\'']%' {ESCAPE '\'}
```

Comment: does not work for oracle db (tested with squirrel or sql developer): "SQL not properly ended"

Comment: The question was specifically asked for SQL Server. +1

Answer (score 3):

```
Select * from TableName Where ColumnName LIKE '%[^A-Za-z0-9, ]%'
```

This will give you all the row which contains any special character.

Comment: An almost identical, but more detailed answer was given 5+ years ago on this. Why the unneeded answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*) from dbo.tablename where address_line_1 LIKE '%[\'']%' {eSCAPE'\'}
```