# How to find the values have '%' in Sql-server

Tags: sql, sql-server

delete member
where accountid like '%%%'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7191456/2864740 (specifically in the duplicate, as it contains a link to MSDN (which will also show the other common recommendation))

Comment: can use xxx `like '%[%]%'` more info ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12897952/18026431

Comment: I've flagged this as a duplicate of the question everyone's linking - once the mods get to this particular question, this will likely be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this syntax:

```
delete member
where accountid like '%[%]%'
```